# How to make Basic authentication on Open Distro?

Tags: elasticsearch-opendistro

I am trying to add an username and password in URL to be able to view an `iFrame` of an account.

I tested :

```
<iframe src="http://user:password@localhost:5601" height="600" width="800"></iframe>
```

But it shows me:

> Something went wrong

Try refreshing the page. If that doesn't work, go back to the previous page or clear your session data.

`/translations/en.json` is an url with embedded credentials.

Version: 6.7.1

Build: 20266

```
Error: /translations/en.json is an url with embedded credentials.
_callee$@http://user:password@localhost:5601/built_assets/dlls/vendors.bundle.dll.js:217:104853
tryCatch@http://user:password@localhost:5601/built_assets/dlls/vendors.bundle.dll.js:345:246774
```

Is there no other solution?

Comment: Can you elaborate why you want to use iFrame? What's your use case?